# VBA Error Run-time error 6 'Overflow', What is the problem?

Tags: excel, vba

I am a Programmer but never use VBA.  I am taking over someone's old script and it keeps failing at a certain point with a Run-Time Error.

[image]

The Debugging report is here:

[image]

Please let me know if you need more code.  I have tried to change currRow to Long, single, double, string none work.  Below is a quick glimpse of the sheet that is failing.  The top row is row one.

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with `Not Cells(currRow, 20)`? Note: screenshots of code aren't allowed, please [edit] your question with the code as text.

Comment: @BigBen not sure, I inherited this script.  I am not even sure what the index is referencing (currRow, 20)  = (row, column)?

Comment: Yes, it's row, column, but the real problem is `Not`. Any chance it's missing an `IsEmpty`? Probably this is a poor attempt to find the last row.

Comment: @BigBen seemed to fix it, the script failed later on in a different sheet so now I gotta figure that one out too haha

Comment: Side notes: don't use `Integer`, [use `Long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).

Comment: @BigBen it failed when using long but will try again with out the Not.  If you fill out as an answer I will get yo u the solution points

Comment: I'm guessing it should be `Not IsEmpty(Cells(currRow, 20))`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234699/discussion-between-d3hero23-and-bigben).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that this is missing an `IsEmpty`:

```
Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(currRow, 20))
```

However, this loop is a very inefficient way to find the last row.

I believe something like this is what you want:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis")
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 20).End(xlUp).Row

    .Range(lastRow + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
End With
```

Additionally:

- Don't use `Integer`, [use `Long`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long).
- [Avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
- [How to find the last used cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba).